# authentication on spagobi using keyrock

Tags: fiware, spagobi, oauth-2.0

We're having troubles authenticating on SpagoBI using KeyRock as authentication provider. We followed the guide here:

http://spagobi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin/README/index.html

The redirection to KeyRock works, but after we enter the user credentials there is an error which says: 
`{"state": "None", "error": "invalid_redirect_uri"} (HTTP 400)`

The configuration page in KeyRock looks like this:

[keyrock screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXsbA.png)

We've simply copied client id, secret and the other parameters required in the oauth2.config.properties.

Note: the default urls for the public instance of KeyRock were wrong, we had to add /oauth2 to make them work, probably they were prepared for a previous version of KeyRock.

**EDIT 30-03-2016**

Some more information:

- we're using the public instance of KeyRock
- we're using a private
  instance of SpagoBI deployed on our servers using the Docker
  container available in docker hub
- This is the the content of our
  oauth2.config.properties
- `CLIENT_ID = 123456
  SECRET = 123456
  REDIRECT_URI = http://192.168.196.15:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE
  TOKENS_URL = https://account.lab.fiware.org/api/v1/tokens.json
  APPLICATIONS_BASE_URL = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/applications/
  AUTHORIZE_BASE_URL = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize
  GET_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token
  GET_USER_INFO_URL = https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/user
  APPLICATION_NAME = SpagoBI
  ADMIN_EMAIL = fiwarelab@email
  ADMIN_PASSWORD = fiwarelab@password`
- We've add the /oauth2/ part in the addresses, otherwhise we would get a 404 error on the redirect to KeyRock.

Comment: Some more information:

Answer (score 0):

You are right: those settings are based on a previous version of KeyRock.
If you want to use the KeyRock public instance, you have to use the "5.1-fiware-all-in-one" docker file, that is more up-to-date. 
Please try with that one and let me know.