# fiware spagobi validation with keyrock instance

Tags: fiware, spagobi

i'm using three instances in my account lab. All of them :

1.-web app and a proxy (ubuntu image)

2.-keyrock 5 (keyrock-R5.1.0 image)

3.-spagobi (spagobi image)

i having troubles setting spagobi to validate with keyrock, as in this link: [authentication on spagobi using keyrock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206819/authentication-on-spagobi-using-keyrock)

"error while trying to get access token from Oauth2 provider"

[image: spagobi oauth2 error]

I followed the guide here:

http://spagobi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin/README/index.html

the only difference is REST_BASE_URL, i change port to **5000**. (default is 4730)

I think the problem is that spagobi tries to access token without X-Auth-Token value on headers. But i don't know where can i set this on spagobi.

Anyone know this problem and how to solve it? or maybe i'm wrong?

my oauth2.config.properties:

```
# Informations about OAuth2 application
CLIENT_ID = ea74f4f72ee3438a82f1af785af0ecf1
SECRET = 21cf7df4633d4ff2b92251c266c00d09
APPLICATION_ID = ea74f4f72ee3438a82f1af785af0ecf1

# OAuth2 urls
AUTHORIZE_URL = http://example.es:8000/oauth2/authorize
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = http://example.es:8000/oauth2/token
USER_INFO_URL = http://example.es:8000/user
REDIRECT_URI = http://example.es:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE

# REST API urls
REST_BASE_URL = http://example.es:5000/v3/
TOKEN_PATH = auth/tokens
ROLES_PATH = OS-ROLES/roles
ORGANIZATIONS_LIST_PATH = OS-ROLES/organizations/role_assignments
ORGANIZATION_INFO_PATH = projects/

# Admin credentials
ADMIN_ID = fiware-example-admin
ADMIN_EMAIL = fiware@example.es
ADMIN_PASSWORD = 01189998819991197253
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. My fault:

because we have not ready the real domain, i add in my /etc/hosts a local resolution. But in spagobi instance i dont do it.

the real problem is in screenshoot:

java.net.UnknownHostException

I solved it adding in /etc/hosts on spagobi instance the same ip.

Sorry for the inconvenience.